# Converting an RDB to RDF with autogenerated code

Tags: rdf, sparql, virtuoso, linked-data

I am using the OpenLink Virtuoso software to convert a Relational Database to RDF using this tutorial: [Automated Generation of Linked Data Views over Relational Data Sources with Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration)

I have a database with 5 tables (`Authors`, `Keywords`, `Publications`, `References`, `Rights`) and I imported them in Virtuoso database using .csv files.

So basically I have followed the steps for the "[Manual Linked Data Generation & Deployment using the Conductor's HTML-based wizard](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration#Manual%20Linked%20Data%20Generation%20&%20Deployment%20using%20the%20Conductor%27s%20HTML-based%20wizard)", because I need to use my own ontologies and this is the code that was generated for the R2RML Graph:

```
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix CSV: <http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/> .
@prefix csv-stat: <http://localhost:8890/CSV/stat#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix void: <http://rdfs.org/ns/void#> .
@prefix scovo: <http://purl.org/NET/scovo#> .
@prefix aowl: <http://bblfish.net/work/atom-owl/2006-06-06/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> . 


<#TriplesMapAuthors_csv> a rr:TriplesMap; 
rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableSchema "CSV" ;         
rr:tableOwner "DBA" ; rr:tableName "Authors_csv" ]; 
rr:subjectMap [ rr:termtype "IRI"  ; 
rr:template "http://localhost:8890/CSV/authors_csv/ID={ID}"; 
rr:class CSV:Authors_csv; rr:graph <http://localhost:8890/CSV#> ];
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:id ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "ID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authorid ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authorname ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorName" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authormidlename ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorMidleName" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authorsurname ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorSurname" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authorurl ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorURL" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authoremail ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorEmail" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:csd_dep ] ; 
rr:objectMap [ rr:column "CSD_DEP" ]; ] .

<#TriplesMapKeywords_csv> a rr:TriplesMap; rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableSchema "CSV" ; rr:tableOwner "DBA" ; rr:tableName "Keywords_csv" ]; 
rr:subjectMap [ rr:termtype "IRI"  ; rr:template "http://localhost:8890/CSV/keywords_csv/ID={ID}"; rr:class CSV:Keywords_csv; rr:graph <http://localhost:8890/CSV#> ];
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:id ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "ID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:keyword ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "Keyword" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:keywordorder ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "KeywordOrder" ]; ] .

<#TriplesMapPublications_csv> a rr:TriplesMap; rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableSchema "CSV" ; rr:tableOwner "DBA" ; rr:tableName "Publications_csv" ]; 
rr:subjectMap [ rr:termtype "IRI"  ; rr:template "http://localhost:8890/CSV/publications_csv/ID={ID}"; rr:class CSV:Publications_csv; rr:graph <http://localhost:8890/CSV#> ];
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:id ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "ID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationtitle ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationTitle" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:mediatype ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "MediaType" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationtype ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationType" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:mediatitle ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "MediaTitle" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:mediapublisher ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "MediaPublisher" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:mediaeditors ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "MediaEditors" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:mediavolinfo ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "MediaVolInfo" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationyear ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationYear" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationnoofpages ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationNoOfPages" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationpagesinmedium ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationPagesInMedium" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationfilename ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationFileName" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationcomments ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationComments" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationrelatedurl ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationRelatedURL" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationrelatedurltext ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationRelatedURLText" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationlocation ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationLocation" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationpuburl ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationPubURL" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:displayonmlkd ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "DisplayOnMLKD" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:displayoniskp ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "DisplayOnISKP" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publishonweb ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublishOnWeb" ]; ] .

<#TriplesMapReferences_csv> a rr:TriplesMap; rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableSchema "CSV" ; rr:tableOwner "DBA" ; rr:tableName "References_csv" ]; 
rr:subjectMap [ rr:termtype "IRI"  ; rr:template "http://localhost:8890/CSV/references_csv/ID={ID}"; rr:class CSV:References_csv; rr:graph <http://localhost:8890/CSV#> ];
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:id ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "ID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:refid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "RefID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:refpaperid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "RefPaperID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:refdetails ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "RefDetails" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:refyear ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "RefYear" ]; ] .

<#TriplesMapRights_csv> a rr:TriplesMap; rr:logicalTable [ rr:tableSchema "CSV" ; rr:tableOwner "DBA" ; rr:tableName "Rights_csv" ]; 
rr:subjectMap [ rr:termtype "IRI"  ; rr:template "http://localhost:8890/CSV/rights_csv/ID={ID}"; rr:class CSV:Rights_csv; rr:graph <http://localhost:8890/CSV#> ];
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:id ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "ID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:publicationid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "PublicationID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authorid ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorID" ]; ] ;
rr:predicateObjectMap [ rr:predicateMap [ rr:constant CSV:authororder ] ; rr:objectMap [ rr:column "AuthorOrder" ]; ] .
```

And this is the Ontology auto-generated code:

```
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix aowl: <http://bblfish.net/work/atom-owl/2006-06-06/> .
@prefix virtrdf: <http://www.openlinksw.com/schemas/virtrdf#> .
@prefix CSV: <http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/> .
@prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> . 
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> . 
@prefix bibo: <http://purl.org/ontology/bibo/> . 

CSV: a owl:Ontology .

# CSV.DBA.Authors_csv
CSV:Authors_csv a rdfs:Class .
CSV:Authors_csv rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:Authors_csv rdfs:label "CSV.DBA.Authors_csv" .
CSV:Authors_csv rdfs:subClassOf foaf:Person .
CSV:id a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:id rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:id rdfs:domain CSV:Authors_csv .
CSV:id rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:id rdfs:label "ID" .
CSV:authoremail a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:authoremail rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:authoremail rdfs:domain CSV:Authors_csv .
CSV:authoremail rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:authoremail rdfs:label "AuthorEmail" .
CSV:csd_dep a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:csd_dep rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:csd_dep rdfs:domain CSV:Authors_csv .
CSV:csd_dep rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:csd_dep rdfs:label "CSD_DEP" .

# CSV.DBA.Keywords_csv
CSV:Keywords_csv a rdfs:Class .
CSV:Keywords_csv rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:Keywords_csv rdfs:label "CSV.DBA.Keywords_csv" .
CSV:id a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:id rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:id rdfs:domain CSV:Keywords_csv .
CSV:id rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:id rdfs:label "ID" .
CSV:publicationid a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:domain CSV:Keywords_csv .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:label "PublicationID" .
CSV:keyword a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:keyword rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:keyword rdfs:domain CSV:Keywords_csv .
CSV:keyword rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:keyword rdfs:label "Keyword" .
CSV:keywordorder a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:keywordorder rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:keywordorder rdfs:domain CSV:Keywords_csv .
CSV:keywordorder rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:keywordorder rdfs:label "KeywordOrder" .

# CSV.DBA.Publications_csv
CSV:Publications_csv a rdfs:Class .
CSV:Publications_csv rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:Publications_csv rdfs:label "CSV.DBA.Publications_csv" .
CSV:Publications_csv rdfs:subClassOf bibo:Article .
CSV:publicationtitle a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationtitle rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:publicationtitle rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publicationtitle rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationtitle rdfs:label "PublicationTitle" .
CSV:mediatype a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:mediatype rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:mediatype rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:mediatype rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:mediatype rdfs:label "MediaType" .
CSV:publicationtype a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationtype rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:publicationtype rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publicationtype rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationtype rdfs:label "PublicationType" .
CSV:mediatitle a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:mediatitle rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:mediatitle rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:mediatitle rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:mediatitle rdfs:label "MediaTitle" .
CSV:publicationyear a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationyear rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:publicationyear rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publicationyear rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationyear rdfs:label "PublicationYear" .
CSV:publicationfilename a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationfilename rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:publicationfilename rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publicationfilename rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationfilename rdfs:label "PublicationFileName" .
CSV:publicationcomments a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationcomments rdfs:range xsd:string .
CSV:publicationcomments rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publicationcomments rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationcomments rdfs:label "PublicationComments" .
CSV:displayonmlkd a owl:ObjectProperty .
CSV:displayonmlkd rdfs:range aowl:Content .
CSV:displayonmlkd rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:displayonmlkd rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:displayonmlkd rdfs:label "DisplayOnMLKD" .
CSV:displayoniskp a owl:ObjectProperty .
CSV:displayoniskp rdfs:range aowl:Content .
CSV:displayoniskp rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:displayoniskp rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:displayoniskp rdfs:label "DisplayOnISKP" .
CSV:publishonweb a owl:ObjectProperty .
CSV:publishonweb rdfs:range aowl:Content .
CSV:publishonweb rdfs:domain CSV:Publications_csv .
CSV:publishonweb rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publishonweb rdfs:label "PublishOnWeb" .

# CSV.DBA.References_csv
CSV:References_csv a rdfs:Class .
CSV:References_csv rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:References_csv rdfs:label "CSV.DBA.References_csv" .
CSV:References_csv rdfs:subClassOf bibo:ReferenceSource .
CSV:refyear a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:refyear rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:refyear rdfs:domain CSV:References_csv .
CSV:refyear rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:refyear rdfs:label "RefYear" .

# CSV.DBA.Rights_csv
CSV:Rights_csv a rdfs:Class .
CSV:Rights_csv rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:Rights_csv rdfs:label "CSV.DBA.Rights_csv" .
CSV:Rights_csv rdfs:subClassOf dcterms:RightsStatement .
CSV:id a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:id rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:id rdfs:domain CSV:Rights_csv .
CSV:id rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:id rdfs:label "ID" .
CSV:publicationid a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:domain CSV:Rights_csv .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:publicationid rdfs:label "PublicationID" .
CSV:authorid a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:authorid rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:authorid rdfs:domain CSV:Rights_csv .
CSV:authorid rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:authorid rdfs:label "AuthorID" .
CSV:authororder a owl:DatatypeProperty .
CSV:authororder rdfs:range xsd:int .
CSV:authororder rdfs:domain CSV:Rights_csv .
CSV:authororder rdfs:isDefinedBy CSV: .
CSV:authororder rdfs:label "AuthorOrder" .
```

In the end of the "convertion" it presents the status of the operations which turn out OK and gives me the following links:

### SQL Relations (Tables) to RDF Statements (Predicate / Property Graph) Mappings

```
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-authors_csv
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-keywords_csv
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-publications_csv
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-references_csv
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-rights_csv
http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/qm-VoidStatistics
```

### Sample Graph IRIs & Linked Data Entity URIs

#### RDFDocument (Named Graph) IRIs:

```
Transient Views: http://localhost:8890/CSV#
http://localhost:8890/CSV/authors_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/authors_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/keywords_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/publications_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/publications_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/objects/publications_csv/ID/1/DisplayOnMLKD.bin
http://localhost:8890/CSV/references_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/references_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/rights_csv/ID/1#this
http://localhost:8890/CSV/rights_csv/ID/1#this
Metadata Data Document (VoiD) URI/URL: http://localhost:8890/CSV/stat#
Linked Data Ontology URI: http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/
```

I tried using the following query to view all the results to check them:

```
SELECT *
FROM <http://localhost:8890/CSV>
WHERE {?s ?o ?p}
```

What the above query returns is nothing, just 3 empty columns with the titles s,o,p.

#### Question:

So based on the above results how can I find where my graphs are stored and what SPARQL queries should I use on my Virtuoso endpoint to view my results?

Comment: For future reference... Questions specifically regarding [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com) are generally best raised on the [public OpenLink Discussion Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support), the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a minor typo in your query.

All punctuation in a URI is significant, your list of graph names shows `http://localhost:8890/CSV#` but you've queried for `http://localhost:8890/CSV` - note the missing `#` sign.

You need to modify your query like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM <http://localhost:8890/CSV#>
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
```

Note that I also change your variable ordering to `?s ?p ?o` rather than `?s ?o ?p`, this makes no difference because variable names are user defined but if you are selecting all triples in a graph it is typical to use `?s ?p ?o` since the names corresponds to the subject, predicate and object of the triples

Comment: Ok I think that was indeed my problem but now I have the following error:
Virtuoso 42000 Error SR186: No permission to execute dpipe DB.DBA.RL_I2ID with user ID 106, group ID 106
SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
SELECT *
FROM 
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
To me it looks like I need to grant some priviledges to a user. But I dont know I am fairly new to this :/

Comment: @sokras That's a different question. Stack Overflow is not just about getting questions answered, but getting them answered in a way that people in the future can find them.  Please ask your new question as a new question, because people won't find it or its answer if they're hidden in the comments.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't realise it. I'll create a new one. :)

Comment: @RobV How can I view each one of the graphs that I created for each table? I mean at the "FROM" what link should I use to view for example only the graph made for the publications table?

Comment: @sokras Again that is a different question so please ask it as such

Comment: Oh ok sorry i am new here :/